# CocoaPods use_frameworks HCSStarRatingView

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have been using pods not problem in my project. I recently added a pod to my podfile "HCSStarRatingView" which in the README says I need to add `use_frameworks!` at the top.

I did that and ran `pod update`. I am no longer able to `#import <>`, `#import ""` or `@import` any of my pods. Parse, MBProgressHUD, etc. None are found with any of those import statements. Also, HCSStarRatingView is not found with any combination of import statement either.

I have deleted my pods directory and ran `pod install` again, which did not fix the issue. My project does not have any Swift. I removed `use_frameworks!` (old pods work) but then I am still unable to import HCSStarRatingView. There are no issues for this on GitHub and I have not found any questions that help with my issue.

I have also cleaned my project as well as the build folder.

Very simple pod file:

```
use_frameworks!

pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'
pod 'ParseUI'
pod 'ParseCrashReporting'
pod 'RSKImageCropper'
pod 'CRToast'
pod 'JSQMessagesViewController'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'HockeySDK',                            '~> 3.8'
pod 'SDWebImage',                           '~> 3.7'
pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage',   '~> 1.2'
pod 'MHVideoPhotoGallery',                  '~> 1.6'
pod 'TDOAuth',                              '~> 1.1'
pod 'HCSStarRatingView',                    '~> 1.4.3'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

Comment: Might be a little off-topic, but I noticed you tagged this `parse.com`. Are you aware that's going away?

Comment: Please show your podfile

Comment: Which version of cocoapods are you using?

Comment: cocoapods version 0.39.0

Comment: Does it work if you run `pod deintegrate` first and then `pod update` again?

Comment: just tried that, no change

Comment: Could you please post the output message when you run `pod update --verbose` as well?

Comment: quite a lot of output [here](http://1drv.ms/1mu0UDR). It's like once I add `use_frameworks!` and pod install, I can't import any 3rd party libraries/frameworks at all. I have had a lingering suspicion that my Xcode installation is corrupted due to previous (unrelated to this) issues. Could it also be project settings incorrect somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103167/discussion-between-raesu-and-david-cheung).

Comment: Have you fixed your problem yet?

Comment: I didn't. I copied in the .h and .m files manually and using it that way.